# Desviando de um obstáculo sem NavMeshAgent

Tags: c#, unity3d

Preciso criar um script de desvio de obstáculos mas eu não posso utilizar o *NavMeshAgent* para isso porque este projeto depende de implementações onde o *NavMeshAgent* não funciona.

Vejam que na imagem abaixo há dois cubos e um obstáculo, o cubo azul representa o player enquanto que o cubo vermelho representa o inimigo. O cubo vermelho possui um Raycast que identifica se o cubo azul está próximo (linha vermelha), e então se locomove na direção cubo azul utilizando um `Vector3.forward` e `LookAt`, mas caso haja algum obstáculo a frente do cubo vermelho a locomoção deve ser modificada para que haja um desvio.

O problema é que estou pensando se o melhor método para desviar do obstáculo seria pegar o tamanho do objeto á frente e calcular a distancia do seu centro até a sua aresta + o tamanho do cubo vermelho para direcionar o cubo vermelho até lá e depois continuar a sua locomoção até o cubo azul. Ou disparar um Raycast rotativo que pegará o caminho livre mais curto e somar a posição. Mas como fazer isso?

Qual seria a forma correta de fazer este desvio? lembrando que não posso utilizar o *NavMeshAgent* em nenhum caso.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Pathfinding sem ser com navmesh num ambiente livre é complicado... Tu pode até não usar o nativo da Unity, mas NavMesh é muito bom pra esse tipo de situação. O que você citou é um método "burro", ele ia funcionar bem com um obstáculo, mas seria horroroso se o ambiente fosse mais complexo, e certamente poderia ficar preso num "U" caso achasse um local sem saída.

Comment: O problema é que o NavMesh da Unity só funciona com terrenos, e eu preciso criar este script para a navegação em uma esfera.

Comment: Ah, se tu vai fazer pathfinding num planeta ou coisa do gênero então tua melhor saída é um A* estrela mesmo ou um derivado dela. http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/53866/pathfinding-on-a-uneven-planetary-surface

Comment: Bom, primeiramente se o seu problema é com uma esfera, deixe isso claro na pergunta. Se possível, forneça também um projeto de exemplo pra que alguém possa te ajudar sem ter o trabalho de criar tudo do zero. O link que o colega @DH. menciona é da melhor pergunta relacionada com o que você precisa. Há [esta outra no SOEn](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35966800/unity-3d-nav-mesh-baking-didnt-cover-all-area), cuja única resposta fornece alguns detalhes interessantes (tutorial pra vc criar um A* na Unity3D, e até um link pra Asset Store com um projeto que já faz o que vc precisa).

Answer (score 2):

Se você só está evitando o navmesh por causa do terreno, saiba que ele funciona em qualquer objeto desde que seja marcado como "static". Você pode ver isso na documentação:

http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/nav-BuildingNavMesh.html (navigation static)

ou, pode ver nesse vídeo onde o navmesh é usado em um cubo:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=45_EABIc7VA

Agora, se nenhuma das soluções acima te ajudarem, o que eu sugeriria para resolver seu problema dos desvios, seria colocar alguns objetos(cubos mesmo) sem box collider e sem mesh renderer. Depois por script você pega eles e checa se o player estiver mais longe que um desses pontos de acesso ou se o raycast detectar um obstaculo, andar até o desvio, depois até o player.

```
public GameObject[] desvios;
private Bool obstaculo = false; // Coloca true quando o raycast pegar
public GameObject player, alvo; //Pra onde o inimigo vai


void Start(){
    desvios = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Desvios");
}
void Update(){
    if(obstaculo){
      Vector3 playerPosition = player.transform.position;
      Float distPlayer = Vector3.distance(playerPosition, this.transform.position); // distancia entre inimigo e player
      for(int i=0; i<desvios.lenght; i++){
         Float distDesvio = Vector3.distance(this.transform.position, desvios[i].trasform.position);
         // Checa se a distancia até o player é maior que a do obstaculo, se move primeiro pro obstaculo (alvo)
         if(playerPosition > distDesvio){
            alvo = desvios[i];
         }
      }
    }
}
```

Espero ter ajudado, boa sorte!